# How to Group Time data into hour sections in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, group

I have a data set with time and heart rate data. The time intervals are currently about 5 seconds apart and each have data for hear rate (i.e 7:21AM = Time, 97 = Value... 7:21:05 = Time, 102 = Value.)I want to group the time into hour so that I can create a line graph of how the heart rate changes from hour to hour. When I attempt to load in the data with this many data points the graph does not load properly. How would I go about doing this to create a clean graph that shows how heart rate changes from 0000 to 0100 to 0200 to 0300.. etc etc?

update -- Okay thank you for suggestions, I have added the visualization I am working with. Essentially I just want to add values across the x axis which represent 7 Am to 8pm.

```
structure(list(Id = c("user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1", 
"user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1"), 
    Time = c("4/12/2016 7:21:00 AM", "4/12/2016 7:21:05 AM", 
    "4/12/2016 7:21:10 AM", "4/12/2016 7:21:20 AM", "4/12/2016 7:21:25 AM", 
    "4/12/2016 7:22:05 AM", "4/12/2016 7:22:10 AM", "4/12/2016 7:22:15 AM", 
    "4/12/2016 7:22:20 AM", "4/12/2016 7:22:25 AM"), Value = c(97L, 
    102L, 105L, 103L, 101L, 95L, 91L, 93L, 94L, 93L)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: enter link description here]

[image]

Comment: It will be much easier for people to help if you can provide code and sample data (fake is just fine) that people can run. It's unclear to me what format your data is in, so I wouldn't know where to start. Great advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example     It's often simplest to edit your question to include the output of `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))`

Comment: I've provided one possible solution, but unsure what your expected output is. Also, as @JonSpring mentions, providing the `dput` would help as dealing with time data is highly dependent upon the format.

Comment: Okay thank you all, I have updated an example(as it is a very large string of data) and the visualization I am currently working on. Check original post for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

We can convert into a `POSIXct` format, then plot the data. We can use `scale_x_datetime` to specify plotting at 1 hour intervals showing just hour, minute, and AM/PM.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(Time = as.POSIXct(strptime(Time, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS %p")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = Value)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = "1 hour", date_labels =  "%I:%M %p")
```

**Output**

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Id = c("user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1", 
"user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1", "user_1", 
"user_1", "user_1"), Time = c("4/12/2016 6:50:00 AM", "4/12/2016 7:21:00 AM", 
"4/12/2016 7:21:05 AM", "4/12/2016 7:21:10 AM", "4/12/2016 7:21:20 AM", 
"4/12/2016 7:21:25 AM", "4/12/2016 7:22:05 AM", "4/12/2016 7:22:10 AM", 
"4/12/2016 7:22:15 AM", "4/12/2016 7:22:20 AM", "4/12/2016 7:22:25 AM", 
"4/12/2016 7:55:20 AM", "4/12/2016 8:05:25 AM"), Value = c(105L, 
97L, 102L, 105L, 103L, 101L, 95L, 91L, 93L, 94L, 93L, 96L, 98L
)), row.names = c(NA, 13L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Original Answer**

If you want to summarise for each hour, then we could just convert the time to the hour, then get the mean of values for that hour, then convert back to a time format for plotting.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(Time = hour(hms(format(strptime(Time, "%I:%M:%S %p"), "%H:%M:%S")))) %>% 
  group_by(Time) %>% 
  summarise(Value = mean(Value)) %>% 
  mutate(Time = paste0(Time, ":00"),
         Time = as_datetime(hm(Time))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = Value)) +
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = "1 hour", date_labels =  "%H:%M %p")
```

*Output*

[image]

*Data*

```
set.seed(200)
time.seq = format(seq(from=as.POSIXct("04:00:00", format="%H:%M:%OS",tz="UTC"),    
               to=as.POSIXct("08:59:59", format="%H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC"), by = 5), "%I:%M:%S%p")
df <- data.frame(Time = time.seq, Value = round(runif(3600, 50, 150), digits = 0))
```

Comment: Okay thank you for the example and thinking of a suggestion. This would work great however I am just looking to add the times to the x axis now (as updated in my original question.) 

Would I just need to use the code
time.seq = format(seq(from=as.POSIXct("07:00:00", format="%H:%M:%OS",tz="UTC"),
to=as.POSIXct("19:00:00", format="%H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC), by = 12), "%I:%M:%S%p")

Comment: In addition - what is the last bit of code referring to? the "%I:%M:%S%p"?

Comment: @Stackstudent_09 I've updated using your data (though I added a time point before 7 am and after 8 am). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you yes, however there is still a problem within the graph. The time label is set from 1:00AM to 13:00 PM. I have added the graph to the original question!

Comment: The data is the same from 7:21 AM to 7:50 PM however the label is showing from 1:00 AM to 1PM.

Comment: @Stackstudent_09 I updated the code in the `mutate` statement to convert to 24 hour format. Then, we can just set the format as AM/PM for the x-axis still in the `scale_x_datetime` function for the plot. This should fix the issue for afternoon times.

Comment: Nice thank you, is there a way to convert 13:00PM through 20:00 to normal time and not millitary?

Comment: @Stackstudent_09 Yeah, use the new code that I have up. I had also changed the last line to use ‘I’ instead of ‘H’. Using ‘I’ will make it not military time for the x axis.

Comment: Great! this is perfect